# Compression CCITT 3 and 4 in .NET

Tags: .net, compression, fax

When compressing a file using CCITT3 or 4 in .NET, the images is really tiny but its always in black and white.  My question is are those formats Black and White Formats only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both the [CCITT Group 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax#Modified_Huffman) and [CCITT Group 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_4_compression) compression algorithms are for bitonal (black and white) images only.